# When a flow unpauses, are its fields from the old version of the record or up to date based on the status of the current record

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a flow that pauses for 2 hours. I am curious if after the pause, does the record begin in a new execution context with the fields that could have potentially updated during that time?

Or do I have to do a lookup to the respective record to get the new fields that may have been updated during that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field values from the original execution context remain constant regardless of the pauses.